# How to set a variable async waterfall?

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm having trouble with setting a variable or at least returning it in async waterfall. I know that you can't return in async but I did a callback on my variable, `jsonFinal` and it goes into the function below under data.

```
function getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, indexIter) {
var individualMatchURL = 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/' + matchData.matchID[indexIter] + '?api_key=' + API_KEY;
var jsonFinal;
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
          request(individualMatchURL, function(err, response, body) {
            if(!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    if (matchData.championID[indexIter] == json['participants'][j].championId) {
                        jsonFinal = json['participants'][j];
                        callback(null, jsonFinal);
                    }
                }
            } 
            else {
                console.log(err);
                }
        });
    }
],
function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        jsonFinal = data;
    }
});
console.log(jsonFinal);
return jsonFinal; 
}
```

How can I get the function to return jsonFinal properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get the variable within the callback like with any asynchronous operation. Therefore, modify your function to also accept a callback.

```
function getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, indexIter, callback) {
    var individualMatchURL = 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matches/' + matchData.matchID[indexIter] + '?api_key=' + API_KEY;
    async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            request(individualMatchURL, function (err, response, body) {
                // always trigger the callback even when you have errors or else your program will hang
                if (err)
                    return callback(err);
                if (response.statusCode != 200)
                    return callback(new Error('Status code was ' + response.statusCode));

                var json = JSON.parse(body);
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    if (matchData.championID[indexIter] == json['participants'][j].championId) {
                        // match found: send back data
                        console.log('inside', json['participants'][j]);
                        return callback(null, json['participants'][j]);
                    }
                }
                // if it reaches this point, no match was found
                callback();
            });
        }
    ], callback); // note: this outer 'callback' is NOT the same as the inner 'callback'
}
```

Then when you call your function e.g.

```
getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(data, participants, indexIter, function (err, json) {
     // you can only get the JSON at this point
     console.log('outside', json);
     matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData[i] = json;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that when I store that into a variable I still get undefined when printed out. Are you sure it is returning that callback? Here is how the variable is stored:

`matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData[i] = getIndividualMatchJSONObjHelper(matchData, matchParticipantData, i, function(err, json) {});`

Comment: Again *you can only get the variable within the callback like with any asynchronous operation*. Your function does not `return` anything, but it does offer a callback that has an argument `json` when its async operation is done. Check edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me understand callbacks a little better. But I'm only concerned about one thing. I noticed that printing the object,
`matchParticipantData.specificParticipantData[i]` does not contain the json in it after the function. I tested this out with a variable that changed in the function but not outside of it. Is there a reason for this? While the json was set, I need it to be in there outside of the function as well

Comment: Check edit.  That would mean that no match was found. Try placing `console.log` within the `for` loop's `if` condition. Also, when working with `async.js` ensure that you always trigger `callback` at least and at most once within the task.

Comment: Yup, I tried printing out the JSON in the function call and it works. But storing that into any variable and printing that variable outside the function call does not work for some reason.